# Thread Performance Penalty

Tags: performance, intel-core-i5, multi-threaded, dual-core

Simulations are invoked from the command line.  A dual-core box (4 logical CPUs or threads) can run 4 simulations (seemingly) simultaneously.

Is there a thought process or a measurement to gain a sense of the performance penalty for running two simulation per core?  Ideally one would be able to measure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer to this, because it depends on lots of things.

- If you calculations are purely CPU bound you probably see a huge jump goignnfrom 2 cores/2 treads to 2 cores/4 treads. Theoretical gain might be 100% in very specific cases.
- If the calculations are purely memory bound (e.g. one tread would already use the maximum available bandwith to the memory) then you would have no gain at all.

It gets more complex when you add cache hits (twice as many simulations is effectively half the CPU cache available per similation), CPU termal behaviour etc.

Given a vareity of programs in a typical system it is reasonable to claim about 1/3rd speed gain by enabling hypertreading on a Intel/AMD CPU. So **in general** this is advantageous.  But the effect varies per program and there have been situations where a 40% speed loss was actually measured.  So the only practical answer is to test it on your specific setup.